# Error while shutting down Ubuntu (installed in VirtualBox)

Tags: virtualbox, shutdown

I am facing following error while shutting down Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit) installed in VirtualBox 4.3.16.

> **The instruction at 0x690ddc25 referenced memory at 0x00000008. The memory could not be read**

My host OS is Windows 7 (64 bit).

Comment: Can you provide the content of `/var/log/syslog`? It likely contains more detailed info about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to duplicate this multiple times over multiple installations of Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit).

> The instruction at 0x690ddc25 *(or similar)* referenced memory at 0x00000008 *(or similar)*. The
>   memory could not be read

VirtualBox 4.3.20
Host is Windows 7pro 64bit
Guest Ubuntu 14.04(64)
AMD Athlon 2 X2 260 Processor, 3200 Mhz
Display
ATI Radeon HD 4250

The known workaround is to uncheck "Enable 3D Acceleration" in VirtualBox display settings. Not a great one since it degrades performance.

The problem has been reported by users here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12772

It has been reported on VirtualBox version 4.3.8 through current on Windows 7 and 8.1